# Convert char to logical operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering if there is an easy way to do this in python.

I have a string that can be delimited by **","** or **"|"**, they basically mean logical operators (respectively **and** and **or** ).

For example str = "(cat,dog)|fish", so the logic for them would be `(cat and dog) or fish`

Then I would have longer phrase like

> "cat and dogs don't like each other, but cats like fish"

I would like to check if that phrase contains above words based on that logic. Basically I am wondering what would be the easiest way to convert those chars (, and |) to logical operators.

Thanks

Comment: you can try: `your_string.replace(',', ' and ').replace('|', ' or ')`

Comment: A dictionary of chars to operations would be a good start

Comment: It seems like what you're really asking is how to parse nested expressions, which is much more difficult than a simple string replacement.